# Can I Instantiate an object of an Interface by the constructor of a class

Tags: java, interface, constructor, instantiation

I have a program code like this.

My Interface is

```
public interface MyInterface {
        public void m1(String name);
        public void m2(int num);
}
```

I have a class that implements above Interface.

```
    public class World implements MyInterface {
        public void m1(String name) {
               System.out.println(name);
        }

        public void m2(int num){
              System.out.println("Number is: "+num);
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
                MyInterface ob1  = new World(); //How it is instantiated
                MyInterface ob2  = new World();   //How this one too is instantiated
                ob1.m1("Jaguar"); 
                ob2.m2(5);

        }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more clear please?

Comment: I'm not sure what your confusion is with that code...

Comment: @Gliptal I was asking how an object is being instantiated by a class constructor. But then I got my answer that it is being assigned to by a instantiating the class.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Above is the reply for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In java when we write some thing as

```
Class1 a= new Class2();
```

what exactly happens is  we are calling the constructor of class2 , which means we are creating a object on the heap of class2 and assigning it to reference variable of type class1 (i.e a). Think of the left part as a remote control and the right part as tv. The left part only control the functions that can  be called on the object created in the right part (Since there maybe more functions in the implementing class than declared in the interface).

If we write something like this :-

```
Class1 a= new Class1();
```

Both reference and object variables are of type Class1 and hence all methods of Class1 can be called.

If we write something like this:-

```
Class1 a= new Class2();
```

All methods of Class2 will be called but restricting to those declared in Class1.

Therefore your inteface is never being instantiated and it cant , Its just providing a type of restriction to the objects created (ob1 and ob2) to call only the two methods m1 and m2 on the objects no matter how many functions are extra added in the World class.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.
Check if I am right: "Because an interface can't be instantiated or allocated memory, so it depends upon the class which implements it and implements its methods and hence, to do we need to do so": 
`MyInterface ob1  = new World();`.

Comment: Yes, interface is meant for that purpose only. It provides a template for creating a class, it cannot be instantiated . Interfaces are meant to be implemented by other classes. Since many different classes may implement the interface in different ways and also add thier own methods MyInterface ob1  = new World() restricts the ob1 object to call methods defined in world class but declared in the interface. The LHS just creates a reference type variable which knows how to point and call the interface methods (and its own method only) upon the instantiated world class object.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is Interface can not be instantiated directly whether it is done by its implemented classes. Your code is perfectly instantiating and assigning to interface.

Comment: So you mean I am instantiating a class and then assigning it to an interface type variable? 
But isn't doing so will allocate the memory of the class type Dog to the baby2 which is an object of type Animal?

Answer (score 1):

Actually here you are instantiating the Object of 'class World' ( with default constructor ) and refering it with the reference of 'MyInterface'.. 
    can be refer as Upcasting , link below will be more helpful in understanding.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/513479/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Upcasting-Class-interface

```
   MyInterface ob1  = new World(); //How it is instantiated
```

and it is perfectly valid.
 But instantiating an interface is not possible like,

```
   INVALID XXXX---> MyInterface obj = new MyInterface(); <----XXXX INVALID
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an implicit argument-less constructor that is added to a class when no other constuctor is explicitly declared.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you cannot instantiate any object of an interface since it is an abstract class. But you can instantiate any concrete class that implements it.
So as Abimaran Kugathasan wrote 
`MyInterface ob1 = new World();` is valid but

```
MyInterface ob1 = new MyInterface();
```

is not. Of course

```
World obj2 = new World();
```

is also valid but uses a narrower variable (containing objects of class `World` or of any of its subclasses)

Answer (score 0):

first thing to note - interface will never ever have constructor or any methods defined inside it.

so we can never ever create an object of interface.

but we can use interface varibale to hold its child object.

```
 MyInterface ob1  = new World(); //How it is instantiated
```

the leftside ob1 is a reference variable not an Object, and its a reference variable of interface.

in java ,upcasting(assigning child object to parent's reference variable) is legal and allowed

so above code works fine.

now will see how its instantiated.

right side we are calling new World() means World class default constrcutor.

Note: when there is no constructor is defined in a class then by default no arg constrcutor will be defined. and if any other constrcuotr is alrady defined then it wont define default no arg constrctor.

so in your case it is using default no arg constrcutor and creating an object of World not interface. and assigning it to interface variable.

so answer to your question is "Nooooooooooooo".